# How to upgrade to SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the difference between SQL2008 and SQL2008 R2?

Should I unintall SQL 2005 and install SQL 2008 Web Edition?

Or

Should I upgrade the SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 Web Edition?

I will also need to make sure the Logins are transferred over as many of my web applications have a Login on SQL2005 server.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I tend to only upgrade due to support, security or functional benefits.

Comment: Upgrading to get the new features of SQL 2008.

Comment: But these are the same features you're not aware of right (i.e. your first quesion)>

Comment: @Chopper3: Exactly. Voice 1: "Oooh, there's a new version, I better upgrade". Voice 2: "Why do you need to upgrade?". Voice 1: "Because it's new?". Upgrades should be undertaken for specific reasons: new features that are needed, security, functionality, end of life, end of support, etc.

Comment: @Joe, with you 100% - it's why I love virtualisation, I have a bunch of 'play' hosts on their own vlan that I can bugger-up a hundred times a day with no risk of killing anything else - THATS where I test new stuff, leaving production as undisturbed as possible.

Answer (score 2):

- Microsoft has a nice page with all new stuff. READ IT. I really love when people come here for question as complicaed as going through a one page HTML document. In any case, there i no reason to install 2008 if you do an upgrade anyway.
- Try doing an in place upgrade. Definitely a lot less trouble than uninstall / reinstall, which will neede all the logins etc. recreated.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx